# What are the drawbacks of using a Lucene directory as a primary file store?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping, file-storage

I want to use a **Lucene** [**MMapDirectory**](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory.html) as a primary file store. Each file would be stored in a separate document as a **byte array** in a [**StoredField**](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html). All file properties that should be searchable, like file name, size etc., would be stored in indexable fields in the same document.

My questions would be:

1. What are the drawbacks of using Lucene directories for storing files, especially with regards to indexing and search performance and memory (RAM) consumption?
2. If this is not a "no-go", is there a better/faster way of storing files in the directory than as a byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

I really love Luсene and consider it to be the best opensource library, but I'm afraid that it's not a good decision to use it as a primary file source due to:

- high CPU/memory overhead
- slow index/query performance
- high HDD utilization and doubled index size
- weak capabilities to recovery

## Long Answer

Under the hood lucene uses the following files to keep all stored fields in one segment:

- the fields index file (.fdx),
- the fields data file (.fdt).

You can read more about how it works in [Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat’s](http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.html) docs.

1. This means in case of any I/O issue it is almost impossible to restore any file.
2. In order to return one file - lucene have to read and decompress binary data from the disc in block-by-block manner. This means high CPU overhead to decompress and high memory footprint to keep the whole file in java heap space. No streaming is also avaialbe - compared to file and network storages.
3. Maximum document size is limited by codec implementation - 2 GB per document
4. Lucene has a unique write-once segmented architecture: recently indexed documents are written to a new self-contained segment, in append-only, write-once fashion: once written, those segment files will never again change. This happens either when too much RAM is being used to hold recently indexed documents, or when you ask Lucene to refresh your searcher so you can search all recently indexed documents. Over time, smaller segments are merged away into bigger segments, and the index has a logarithmic "staircase" structure of active segment files at any time. This architecture becomes a big problem for file storage:

   - you can not delete file - only mark as unavailable
   - merge operation requires 2x disc space and consumes a lot of resources and disc throughput - it creates new .fdt file and copies content of other .fdt files thru java code and java heap memory

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed answer. As I'm new to Lucene, I'm so enthusiastic that I try to tackle anything related to searching AND storing data by using Lucene only. I'm glad that people like you take their time to inform "newbies" like me that it also has some "weaknesses" and is not the best/optimal solution for every problem :)

Answer (score 1):

So you won't be using MMapDirectory but an actual lucene index.

I have made good experiences with using lucene as the primary data-store for some projects.

Just be sure to also include a generated/natural unique ID, because the document IDs are not constant or reliable.

Also make sure you use a Directory implementation fitting to your use-case. I have switched to the normal RandomAccess implementation in the low-load case, since it uses less memory and is almost as fast.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. May I ask if you have ever had durability issues when using Lucene indexes as data stores? According to articles I have read, an index as well as all stored data should be persistent after calling `IndexWriter.commit()`. In practice, have you ever faced issues with not-recoverable data or totally corrupted indexes? Obviously I would not use Lucene for storing a lot of files if I knew that a single write error or system crash could corrupt the whole storage.